# Binomial sum with factorial

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Counting certain planar paths led me to this sum:
$$
S(n) \;=\;\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k!
$$
Does this have a known expression in terms of $n$?
If not, an approximation would suffice for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n!(1+1+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!})=\lfloor n!e\rfloor$

Comment: Nice---Thanks!${}$

Comment: There's an exception in the case $n=0$.